# PHP send mail through postfix

Tags: php

I have Postfix and SquirrelMail configured on my server. And user called `noreply`. So, I am logging to SquirrelMail and sending email to some address. Everything works fine, i am receiving email from `noreply@mydomain.com`. But when I try to send email from php using `mail()`,

```
mail ('test@2ether.net', 'Postfix Test', 'A test email');
```

server tries to send it from address `www-data@mydomain.com`. How do I configure it to send emails from `noreply@mydomain.com`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php check aditional headers. you need to add from

Comment: What have you tried to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Indra You have time to edit your comment and to replace the reference URL with an English one https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - Always use English references in this area of Stack.

Comment: @NicoHaase sounds like he's a sysadmin trying to prove php can actualise his settings

Comment: @MrHeelis I don't think the OP is a sysadmin

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah, did it. Chrome is driving me nuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [PEARMail](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail) it is designed to counter such issues, (PHP's "`mail()`" method is all but useless in today's email meta - too many bots used it ) however the actual answer is this:

```
$to      = 'test@2ether.net';
$subject = 'Postfix Test';
$message = 'A test email';
$headers = 'From: noreply@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: noreply@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```